Evaluating $\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k^2+5k+2}{3k^2+5k-2}$
Evalute:$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k^2+5k+2}{3k^2+5k-2}$$
If I replace $k$ with the values from $1$ to $n$, I get:
$$\frac{5}{3} \cdot \frac{6}{5} \cdot \frac{11}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{6} \cdot \frac{10}{11} \cdot n \dots \frac{3n^2+5n+2}{3n^2+5n-2}$$
The product of the $5$ fractions is $\frac{7}{3}$
This product is a bit difficult because I don't know if you can use partial fraction as in the sum series.If not, how can I solve this?

There is no series here.

@JoséCarlosSantos Then what do you call it and how can it be solved?I'm stuck at getting the constant 7/3 and I have no idea how to go on!

It's a product.

@JoséCarlosSantos And the hint is? Or the method of solving is......?

Hint: factorise $3k^2+5k+2$ and $3k^2+5k-2$.

A hint for what? I don't know what is it that you are asking and I see no connection betweeen$$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{3k^2+5k+2}{3k^2+5k-2}$$and$$\frac53\times\frac65\times\frac{11}{10}\times\frac76\times\frac{10}{11}\times\cdots\times\frac{3n^2+5n+2}{3n^2+5n-2}.$$

Surely @JoséCarlosSantos he's just evaluated the first few terms and done a lot of (imho) unwise cancelling.

@ancientmathematician   I factored the nominator and denominator and I get $$\frac{(3k+2)*(k+1)}{(3k-1)(k+2)}$$

@ancientmathematician After the factoring what do I do?

Split into two products $$ \prod \frac{k+1}{k+2} \times \prod \frac{3k+2}{3k-1} $$ and evaluate each separately. Btw product of first 5 fractions I get $17/7$ instead of $7/3$

@MyMolecules thanks for clarifying!

barbos: you only thought about my hint for 14 minutes before you asked "what next?" You'll never learn to solve problems if you don't take time to think about them.

My solution:
divide numerator and denominator by 3
$$P=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{3k^2+5k+2}{3k^2+5k-2})= \prod_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{k^2+\frac{5}{3}k+\frac{2}{3}}{k^2+\frac{5}{3}k-\frac{2}{3}})$$
then factor
$$P=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k+\frac{2}{3})(k+1)}{(k-\frac{1}{3})(k+2)}$$
then break into two products
$$P=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+\frac{2}{3}}{k-\frac{1}{3}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{k+1}{k+2})$$
For the first product notice the cancellations
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+\frac{2}{3}}{k-\frac{1}{3}}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k+2}{3k-1}=\frac{5}{2}*\frac{8}{5}*\frac{11}{8}*\frac{14}{11}...*\frac{3n+2}{3n-1}=\frac{3n+2}{2}$$
And a similar process for the second
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{k+2}=\frac{2}{3}*\frac{3}{4}*\frac{4}{5}*\frac{5}{6}...*\frac{n+1}{n+2}=\frac{2}{n+2}$$
multiplying the two answers yields the result of
$$S(n)=\frac{3n+2}{n+2}$$

Motivation:
Look at the product attained:
$$\frac{5}{3} \cdot \frac{6}{5} \cdot \frac{11}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{6} \cdot \frac{10}{11} \cdot \dots \frac{3n^2+5n+2}{3n^2+5n-2}$$
Surely something strikes out? The cancellations in the numerator and denominator!
With this is mind, we try to factorise.

Solution:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k^2+5k+2}{3k^2+5k-2}$$
can be factorised into two smaller products. How? Individually factorise the numerator and denominator first.
$$3k^2+5k+2 = (3k+2)(k+1)$$
$$3k^2+5k-2 = (3k-1)(k+2)$$
So you obtain,
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(3k+2)(k+1)}{(3k-1)(k+2)}$$
Now, you need to ask yourself a crucial question. What was the purpose of factorisation? Cancellation!  How can you achieve this? By splitting the product into two, and it should now be obvious which factors you pair.
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{k+2} \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k+2}{3k-1}$$
Now, to get the cancellation, we can do a quick manipulation
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k-1)+ 2}{k+2} \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k+2}{3(k-1)+2}$$
Hopefully, this should make sense.
Analyse the first product. It should be clear that all middle terms cancel out. What remains is the numerator at $k=1$ and the denominator at $k=n$. What is that?
$$\frac{2}{n+2} \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k+2}{3(k-1)+2} $$
All right, now analyse the second product. Again, it is clear that only the denominator at $k=1$ and the numerator at $k=n$ remain, and everything else is cancelled out. This gives:
$$ \frac{2}{n+2} \cdot \frac{3n + 2}{2}$$
Finally, the answer is:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k^2+5k+2}{3k^2+5k-2} = \frac{3n+2}{n+2}$$

Reflection:
If you are at all familiar with telescoping series and sums, this should seem remarkably familiar. We did the same thing with products! Look out for cancellations in products, especially when the terms look familiar. If you can't find any, try factorising.
